# Hackerrank problem -"Another Prime Problem"

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, primes

I came across this issue in the problem titled: [Another Prime Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/acm-vit-cpp/challenges/another-prime-problem/problem). Here's my solution with JavaScript which passed test case-1, but for other test cases it led to timeout.

```
function processData(input) {
       input=input.split('\n');
       input.shift();
       for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
          values(input[i]);
       }
    } 
    function values(num){
       var sum=0;
       num=num.split(' ');
       for(var i=num[0];i<=num[1];i++){
           for(var j=2;j<=i;j++){
               if(i%j==0 && isprime(j)){
                   sum+=j;
               }
           }
       }
       console.log(sum)
    }
    function isprime(val){
       let flag=1;
       for(var i=2;i<val;i++){
            if(val%i==0){
               flag=0;
            }
       }
       if(flag==1){
          return true;
       }
       else{
           return false;
       }
    }
```

What's the issue in this code that leads to timeout?

The above program has a very bad time complexity, I guess due to multiple loops and functions, but not being much experienced with algorithms this is only solution I can think of right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Additional info:

Problem statement in a nutshell: find the sum of prime factors of each number in the range [X,Y].

Input Format:
The first line contains T denoting the total number of testcases.
First line of each testcase contains two integers X and Y.

Constraints:
1 ≤ T ≤ 10000
2 ≤ X ≤ Y ≤ 10^5

Output Format:
Sum of prime factors of each number in the range [X, Y].

Currently my code calculates the sum of primes (i know this cause I'm able to pass first test case) but the remainder of test cases lead to Timeout.

Comment: When trying to check 9999899999, what information is to be expected from divisors beyond 99999?

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE.

Comment: @greybeard edited..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An immediate problem is that `is_prime()` is expensive, and you call it too many times. Prepare a sufficiently large list of primes in advance (and use a sieve for that).

This will give you a certain performance boost, but I am positive it will not be enough to avoid timeouts. The real problem is with the algorithm: you try to factorize the numbers, and the factorization is hard.

Instead of bruteforcing, do the math homework: how many numbers in the range have a prime \$p\$ as a factor? Hint: if there are `N` of them, they'd contribute `N * p` to the answer.